# What is the purpose of pushsharp broker's iscomplete property?

Tags: pushsharp

There is a mysterious property called iscomplete that is found in brokers and I wonder what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really pretty simple and not that interesting....

`ServiceBroker` uses a `BlockingCollection<T>` to handle queuing notifications.  When you call `.Stop()` on `ServiceBroker` it waits for the collection to be completed before returning (so you have a way to wait for all notifications to be sent from the queue before returning).

The `IsCompleted` property just exposes the collection's same property.  It may or may not be useful to you.

Comment: Am I right in saying that the IsCompleted flag is true when there are no items left in the collection? There is a chance there are still ServiceWorkers still processing notifications. I need an IsCompletedSending flag for my logic I believe!